# VisualStudio doesn't recognize a new reference that I add

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have written a DLL and then in my solution I am adding a reference to it, but when I declare it in the usings section, it gives me error that this is not recognized, are you missing a reference?

here is how I set up my solution...

1- First I had created my DLL. Let's name it MyDLLLibrary, sitting somewhere on hard drive.

2- I also had a solution, consisting of several other projects...for all of these I have created a folder like "C:\_debug" and I have set "Output Path" and "Reference Path" of all these projects to point to that common folder. So far, s good.

3- Now I add that MyDLLLibrary to this solution, change its "Output" and Reference Path to point to the same common debug folder, use Add Refrence and at the reference to MyDLLLibrary to the project I want in the solution and rebuild the solution...

Now if I use a using statement, still it doesn't recognize it.

I even tried the add refrence from projects tab..that didn't work either.

Comment: Did you try restarting Visual Studio?

Comment: Might be a silly question - but does the namespace you are trying to access have a public class?

Comment: actually good thing to check...yeah they were public..issue was that that DLL was compiled with .NET 4 and the rest of the solution were compiledwith .NET 3.5

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the project properties of both assemblies and make sure that the framework setting for both is .NET Framework 4 and not .NET 4.0 Client Profile or something else.

Answer (score 0):

While using Visual Studio 2017, I had to close visual studio and delete the `.vs` folder (at the root of the solution). This fixed my issues